# Using sed, for every occurrence of a string, except the first, delete two lines

Tags: regex, sed

I have a bunch of text files that were generated from TN3270 screens that contain an annoying 2-line header every 24 lines. The first line of each header contains "X310A000", but I want to keep the first occurrence of the header (which is not on the first line).

I can delete all the headers with

```
 sed '/X310A000/{N;d}' $file
```

but my attempt at printing everything up to the first occurrence and *then* deleting the rest of the headers is not working:

```
sed '1,/X310A000/p;/X310A000/,$ /X310A000/{N;d}' $file
sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown command: `/'
```

What can I do?

Comment: `sed -n -e '1,/X310A000/{p; n; }' -e '/X310A000/{N; d; }' -e p "$file"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add additional curly braces for the second range:

`sed '1,/X310A000/p;/X310A000/,${/X310A000/{N;d}}' $file`

Comment: Thanks! While that does correct my syntax error, it doesn't fix the initial problem.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I got it! I just needed to change my `p` to an `n`

Comment: Perhaps `1,/X310A000/b;//{N;d}' file`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give `awk` a chance then it is much easier:

```
awk 'index($0, "X310A000") { if (p) {getline; next} else p=1 } 1' file
```

This command toggles a flag `p` to `1` when it encounters pattern first time. Once flag is set it will skip line with the pattern and the next line from output.